# How to give an 'editor' role rebuild/clear cache permission?

Tags: 8

I'm setting up an "editor" role for a D8 site. I noticed there's no "Flush all caches" in the Tools menu. I don't see any permission setting related to caches. How to enable cache clearing/cache rebuilding for non-admins?

Comment: On all projects I have worked so far there was always a custom route with a button to do that due to "administer site configuration" is just too powerful to give to editor or any non-superadmin role.

Comment: Agreed that "admin site config" is too powerful of a permission. Have you seen any discussion on why clearing cache isn't broken out to it's own permission?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd like to mind the following answer to a similar [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2870483) on DO:

> I kind of disagree with this because of the that shouldn't be
>   necessary in the first place. With cache tags, any change that an
>   editor can make should automatically invalidate all relevant caches.
>   Anything else is a bug IMHO.

Nevertheless in real world sometimes it may be necessary to have other roles than the one with `administer site configuration` being able to rebuild caches.

Basically all you need to do is to build a trigger of some kind (button, route etc.) and let it fire [`drupal_flush_all_caches()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.5.x). Have a look at the Devel module for a great example of this approach.

---

Since I was in need of this myself – which was why I came here in the first place – I finally built a small module and published it on DO. It adds *its own permission* and places a *button on the admin toolbar* from which every user with the new permission is now able to flush all caches:

https://www.drupal.org/project/rebuild_cache_access

[image: Drupal flush cache permission module]

Answer (score 8):

To access this, they would need the `administer site configuration` permission.

From `system.routing.yml`:

```
system.performance_settings:
  path: '/admin/config/development/performance'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\system\Form\PerformanceForm'
    _title: 'Performance'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```