# How do I grant to a role the permission to flush the cache?

Tags: 8, caching

I removed the *Administer site configuration* permission from a role, but I need users with that role to flush the cache from /admin/config/development/performance.

I know, there is `hook_menu_alter()` in Drupal 7, but what about Drupal 8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give an 'editor' role rebuild/clear cache permission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234270/how-to-give-an-editor-role-rebuild-clear-cache-permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the permission used to access a route, as described in [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones). In the specific case, the code used in `alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)` would be the following one.

Since the *administer site performance* permission is a custom one, it needs to be added as new permission by the module that implements the route subscriber class, as described in [How to create a custom permission on Drupal 8 - 9](https://www.lilengine.co/articles/how-create-custom-permission-drupal-8-9).

For a module whose machine name is *mymodule*, the code would be similar to the following one.

#### mymodule.permissions.yml

```yaml
administer site performance:
  title: 'Administer site performance'
  description: 'Access the site performance settings page.'
  restrict access: true
```

#### mymodule.services.yml

```yaml
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

#### src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

```php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('system.performance_settings')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_permission', 'administer site performance');
    }
  }

}
```

If the users with that role should not access the settings in that page (*Caching* and *Bandwidth optimization*), but only be able to clear the cache, I would implement a custom route that shows a confirmation form and clear the cache (which means calling [`drupal_flush_all_caches()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.9.x)) when the user confirms the operation.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: That would be an awesome answer for https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234270/how-to-give-an-editor-role-rebuild-clear-cache-permission

Comment: @leymannx I should expand the answer to show more code than it does, including the code to use in the second scenario.

Comment: The current suggestion is exactly what I was looking for.